# Update Callback status in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have developed a GUI interface in MATLAB. When I push a button search, I have seen the desirable result. However, when I change the textbox and push the search button again, it does not work and gives me following error:

```
Undefined function 'untitled2' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled2('edit1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Undefined function 'untitled2' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled2('pushbutton16_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I must re-execute the all code! Is any way to repeatedly run the GUI?

As seen, when I change the Video ID to other number and push the search button, the results are not updated.

```
function pushbutton16_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton16 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%pathname='C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final\video detail\';
string1 = get(handles.edit1,'UserData');
fName=strcat(cd,'\Video Detail\Video Detail',string1);
fid = fopen(fName);
if fid~=-1
 s{1} = fgetl(fid);
 s{2} = fgetl(fid);
 s{3} = fgetl(fid);
 s{4} = fgetl(fid);
 s{5} = fgetl(fid);
 s{6} = fgetl(fid);
 s{7} = fgetl(fid);

set(handles.text4,'Visible','On');
set(handles.edit1,'Visible','On','String',s{1})
set(handles.edit2,'Visible','On','String',s{2})
set(handles.edit3,'Visible','On','String',s{3})
set(handles.edit4,'Visible','On','String',s{4})
set(handles.edit5,'Visible','On','String',s{5})
set(handles.edit6,'Visible','On','String',s{6})
set(handles.edit7,'Visible','On','String',s{7})
set(handles.axes4,'Visible','On');
cd './Images';
A = imread(s{1});
axes(handles.axes4)
imshow(A);

else
 set(handles.text3,'Visible','On','String','File is not exist !') 
end
```

Comment: Is the declaration for `untitled2` the following:  `function varargout = untitled2(varargin)`?  It should be the top line in the .m file.

Comment: Thank you for respond. Yes the declaration is function varargout = untitled2(varargin)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this line "string1 = get(handles.edit1,'UserData');"

try this one
string1 = get(handles.edit1,'String');

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of weird things going on in `pushbutton16_Callback`:

- You don't need to keep setting `'Visible','on'` for all your editboxes
- `get` `'String'` like amir nemat said, not `'UserData'`
- Use `fullfile` instead of `strcat`
- Don't forget `fclose(fid)`!
- Don't do `cd './Images'` in a callback unless you `cd` back but even then it's not a good idea, just `imread` into that path.
- Do `imshow(A,'Parent',handles.axes4)` instead of `axes(handles.axes4); imshow(A);`

Also, you might want to rename your GUI to something other than `untitled2`.  ;)

As for why you are getting the error, I don't know for sure, but I suspect when `gui_mainfcn` tries to `feval` your `untitled2.m` to run the callback, it is running something else.  Check for other `untitled2` MATLAB-executable files:  `which -all untitled2`.

Comment: Thanks for your respond.  >> which -all untitled2
'untitled2' not found.

Comment: Are you starting the GUI from the GUIDE editor then?  If so, close it down, save and change directory to the location of `untitled2.m/.f` (assuming you did it with a .m and .fig) and run `untitled2`.  See what happens then.  If you get the same error, I'd have to ask if you renamed these files manually at any point - that can break callbacks badly.

Comment: You know what... I think it's that `cd './Images'` that was breaking it!  Fix that first and see.

Comment: No I start from my editor. I have change it to name "amir" but it just same as before. gives me error Undefined function 'untitled2' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled2('pushbutton16_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback Dear Chappjc, if I remove cd './Images', it also does not change. :(

Comment: That demonstrates why you can't just rename it... the original name is stuck all over the code.  Just rename back.  Make sure the path to the .m file is on your `path`

Answer (score 0):

You problem can come that you change your working folder when you use :

```
cd './Images';
```

A possible correction could be :

```
oldPath = cd('./Images'); % Return the path that you were before
A = imread(s{1});
axes(handles.axes4)
imshow(A);

cd(oldPath);  % Go back in the folder with all your functions
```